# Is it against code to secure junction box using Liquid Nails?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I need to extend a 14/2 WG wire a few feet. To do this I want to add the extra wire using a junction box. The problem is that I can't get a good angle to nail the junction box down so I was wondering if using Liquid Nails would be against code?

Comment: what country/state?

Comment: If you post a pic of where you want the junction box we may have other suggestions.

Comment: I very much doubt that it is legal anywhere.

Comment: metallic, or non-metallic box?

Comment: I have been in similar situations and have instead drilled a hole in the box where I could access it and nailed or screwed it in place from there.  If you still have problems reaching it with a nail then a good nail punch will allow you to finish the nail in tight places.

Comment: If you are "extending" a wire, shouldn't there already be a junction box where it ends now? Also be aware that code requires the junction box be accessible, so if you're relocating a fixture or something you can't just wall over the junction.

Answer (score 4):

Article 314.23(B) of the National Electrical Code, says that the enclosure must be *rigidly* supported.

> **NEC 2008**
>   **314.23 Supports.**
>   **(B) Structural Mounting** An enclosure supported from a structural member of a building or from grade shall be rigidly supported either
>   directly or by using a metal, polymeric, or wood brace.

Whether or not liquid nails would meet this criteria may be up to interpretation, so it's best to check with your local inspector to determine if they'd allow it.

The other (better) option, would be to use an *old work* box. Which is allowed by subsection C of the same section.

> **NEC 2008**
>   **314.23 Supports.**
>   **(C) Mounting in Finished Surfaces.** An enclosure mounted in a finished surface shall be rigidly secured thereto by clamps, anchors,
>   or fittings identified for the application.